# Mongoose model field unique

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem when I create products with the field `ref`. In some cases `ref` contains a unique value but when it does not have a value fill it as `undefined`. So when the value is `undefined` is when I have the mongoose exception when there are several documents as `ref: undefined`.

Can a field be set as unique but allow a value as a duplicate, in this case undefined or an empty string?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const productSchema = new Schema(
  {
    ref: { type: String, unique: true, trim: true },
    name: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    description: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
  }
);

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports = Product;
```

Comment: You are probably looking for the `sparse` option in MongoDB. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try  `ref: { type: String, unique: true, trim: true, sparse: true }`